# How to hide table row based on option value in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I have a dropdown..

```
<select ng-model="dropdown">
    <option ng-value="1">1</option>
    <option ng-value="2">2</option>
    <option ng-value="all">All</option>
</select>
```

and a table..

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
        <td ng-bind="d.number"></td> // 0 or 1
        <td>Other TD's</td>
        <td>Other TD's</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I wanted to do is to when I select for example number `2` in the dropdown, all other rows in the table will be hidden except the row with `ng-bind="d.number"` that is equal to `2`.

So what I tried so far is this

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in data" ng-if="d.number == dropdown">
        <td ng-bind="d.number"></td> // 0 or 1
        <td>Other TD's</td>
        <td>Other TD's</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But when I select `all` in the dropdown, the table is empty already.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe have you tried something like: <tr ng-repeat="d in data" ng-if="d.number == dropdown || d.number == 'all'">

Comment: maybe use filter? something like that `<tr ng-repeat="d in data | filter:{number:dropdown}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the angular `filter` to do that like below : 
   [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EhoJmVrdxH8qgQ6HylfL?p=preview)

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="d in data | filter: {number: dropdown||undefined}">
 <td ng-bind="d.number"></td> // 0 or 1
 <td>Other TD's</td>
 <td>Other TD's</td>
</tr>
</table>
```